# From xml want to fetch subchapter number in xref in html using XSL

Tags: xslt-2.0

From xml want to fetch subchapter number of subchapter in xref in html using XSL. I am not able to count and fetch the correct sub-chapter numbering in xref link text.

Scenario in xml: xref is added in subchapter 2.2 and referenced to subchapter 1.2, subchapter 2.1 and 1.3

Expected result in html from xml

In html output xref should append the correct number such as Sub-section 1.2, Sub-section 2.1 and Sub-section 1.3 respectively.

Note: Number in subchapter as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc is given for reference & for better understanding.

Solution required - Need to count chapter and subchapter sequence to fetch the correct subchapter number in xref link.

Sample xml (chapter is referred to diagnostic_adt/diagnostic_adt and subchapter is referred to as diagnostic_adt/diagnostic_adt/diagnostic_adt).

I have used the provided solution to get the number but I am not able to get the number in html.

sample xsl below

```
<xsl:key name="element-by-id" match="*[@id]" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="xref[key('element-by-id', substring(@href, 2))]">
      
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('element-by-id', substring(@href, 2))" mode="compute-number"/>
      
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="diagnostic_adt" mode="compute-number">
      <xsl:number level="multiple" count="/*//diagnostic_adt"/>
  </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="xref">
    
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when>
            <xsl:variable name="xrefid" select="translate(@href, '#', '')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="nos"><xsl:apply-templates select="key('element-by-id', substring(@href, 2))" mode="compute-number"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="countN">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($xrefid,'idSE')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(//diagnostic[contains(@id,$xrefid)]/preceding-sibling::*[name()='diagnostic'])+1" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($xrefid,'idT')">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="contains($xrefid,'idTa')">
                                <xsl:value-of select="count(//table[contains(@id,$xrefid)]/preceding-sibling::*[name()='table'])+1"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <!--<xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor-or-self::diagnostic_adt[contains(@id,$xrefid)]/diagnostic_adt)+1"/>.<xsl:value-of select="count(//diagnostic_adt[contains(@id,$xrefid)]/preceding-sibling::diagnostic_adt)+1"/>-->
                                
                                <xsl:value-of select="$nos"/>           
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>   
                    </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>

        
            <script type="text/javascript">
                generateIntXref( "<xsl:call-template name="get-label"><xsl:with-param name="code" select="'CLIQUER-ICI'"/></xsl:call-template><i>(
         <xsl:value-of select='$countN'/>)</i>.", "<xsl:value-of select='$xrefid'/>", "<xsl:value-of select='$countN'/>" );
            </script>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

sample xml

```
<diagnostic_adt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" appl="" id="TEMPLATE" xml:lang="en" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:ptc:names:renault:dita:xsd:diagnostic_adt.xsd">
   <diagtitle translate="yes">Test xref</diagtitle>
   <diagbody>
   </diagbody>
   <diagnostic_adt id="idSE1">
      <diagtitle translate="yes">chapter 1</diagtitle>
      <diagbody>
         <para translate="yes">
            To return to the previous screen, click here:
            <END-PROCEDURE />
         </para>
      </diagbody>
      <diagnostic_adt id="idT1">
         <diagtitle translate="yes">sub-chapter 1.1</diagtitle>
         <diagbody>
            <para translate="yes">Test</para>
         </diagbody>
      </diagnostic_adt>
      <diagnostic_adt id="idT2">
         <diagtitle translate="yes">sub-chapter 1.2</diagtitle>
         <diagbody>
            <para translate="yes">Test</para>
         </diagbody>
      </diagnostic_adt>
      <diagnostic_adt id="idT5">
         <diagtitle translate="yes">sub-chapter 1.3</diagtitle>
         <diagbody>
            <para translate="yes">Test</para>
            <para translate="yes">
               <xref format="dita" href="#idT2" scope="local" translate="yes" type="diagnostic_adt" />
            </para>
         </diagbody>
      </diagnostic_adt>
   </diagnostic_adt>
   <diagnostic_adt id="idSE2">
      <diagtitle translate="yes">chapter 2</diagtitle>
      <diagbody>
         <para translate="yes">
            To return to the previous screen, click here:
            <END-PROCEDURE />
         </para>
      </diagbody>
      <diagnostic_adt id="idT3">
         <diagtitle translate="yes">sub-chapter 2.1</diagtitle>
         <diagbody>
            <para translate="yes">
               <xref format="dita" href="#idT2" scope="local" translate="yes" type="diagnostic_adt" />
            </para>
            <para translate="yes">
               <xref format="dita" href="#idT5" scope="local" translate="yes" type="diagnostic_adt" />
            </para>
            <para translate="yes">
               <xref format="dita" href="#idT4" scope="local" translate="yes" type="diagnostic_adt" />
            </para>
         </diagbody>
      </diagnostic_adt>
      <diagnostic_adt id="idT4">
         <diagtitle translate="yes">sub-chapter 2.2</diagtitle>
         <diagbody>
            <para translate="yes">
               <xref format="dita" href="#idT3" scope="local" translate="yes" type="diagnostic_adt" />
            </para>
            <para translate="yes">
               <xref format="dita" href="#idT5" scope="local" translate="yes" type="diagnostic_adt" />
            </para>
            <para translate="yes">
               <xref format="dita" href="#idT2" scope="local" translate="yes" type="diagnostic_adt" />
            </para>
         </diagbody>
      </diagnostic_adt>
   </diagnostic_adt>
</diagnostic_adt>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to edit the question? i am not able to do it.... so that i can reduce the xsl sample

Comment: I have cut short the xsl sample, i have to create a variable and call the variable inside <xsl:choose/> but not sure how with help of variable i can generate the sub-chapter number in xref, need help

Comment: Do not use  xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZx/1 online transformation as this does not give the appropriate result, this tools shows number is getting generated but when i go and validate in actual tool for transformation or i use notepad++ with xslt plug-in both the cases ur provided solution does not generate any number. Please validate your solution with some better transformation tool

Comment: In my opinion, xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net is one of the best online xslt tools around. Mainly because it supports multiple processors; especially those that support xslt 3.0. This is most likely where you’re running into trouble. You’ve created an 3.0 xslt but notepad++ and whatever “actual tool for transformation” you’re using doesn’t support 3.0.

Comment: My actual tool ATX latest version support xslt 3.0 which is not working there as expected but the actual system where i want this solution may not support xslt 3.0, so my requirement as mentioned in my question is on xslt 1.0 or 2.0, can you please provide a solution which works in xslt 1.0 and 2.0. Thanks in advance

Comment: my requirement is for output type HTML and which works with  xslt 1.0 and 2.0, please do the needful

Comment: ATX 7.1 should support xslt 3.0 but not completely sure about it, since xslt 1.0 and 2.0 works fine, i can validate the solution and can be used in the system where it needs. so solution in xslt 1.0 and 2.0 will be helpful and highly appreciated